# Autolayout Ambiguous WTF! UIViewController's ___LayoutGuide properties ambiguous

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, autolayout

When I pause my app in the debugger and

`po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] _autolayoutTrace]`

The recursive description that comes out the other end shows the following:

```
*<UIWindow:0xc03d900> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   *<UILayoutContainerView:0xc070ac0>
<<SNIP>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x134b6240> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x1348a2f0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
```

Okay, well my guess is those are UIViewController's `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` properties, but how and why are they ambiguous?

These print as ambiguous regardless of which of my view controller subclasses is front most. My content view controllers are being nested inside of `UINavigationController` installed inside of a `UITabBarController`. There's nothing surprising or unusual about the setup. `UIViewController` subclasses, `UITableViewController` subclasses - doesn't matter, guides still are ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I filed a bug report about this a month ago (rdar://15402294) http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5327306709008384

Apple only asked for a sample project afterwards and the issue is still open. You can file a duplicate bug report. The more bug reports they have, the quicker they fix the issue.

**UPDATE:** my bug report was closed as a duplicate of 10535951 (Open), so it's probably a known issue.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the work-around in OpenRadar. It still seems to be necessary in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

No one outside of Apple probably knows the answer to this question. The iOS system sets the view controller's top and bottom layout guides and _UILayoutGuide is private API. So we're only left with speculation.

In a sense, I see no reason why the term ambiguous would even be applicable to a layout guide. A layout guide is only used as a sort of proxy for a root view's chrome—a status and navigation bar at the top, or a tool bar at the bottom. Their only purpose is to help views position themselves along the vertical axis. Therefore, I see no reason why layout guides would even need any sort of horizontal alignment. And without horizontal alignment, a layout guide would be left permanently ambiguous.

In fact, if you log a top layout guide object, you get a rect with an origin of (0,0) and a width of 0:
<_UILayoutGuide: 0x89c7f60; frame = (0 0; 0 20);

It seems unfair that these hidden layout guides are being judged so harshly by the Auto Layout system. Their ambiguous state is an unsightly blemish on an otherwise beautiful _autolayoutTrace log.

Answer (score 0):

Ambiguous layout generally means you don't have enough constraints to fully define the layout.  My guess without seeing your storyboard or nib constraints is that you need some defining constraints for either your current view or the containing view your constraints attach to.

Can you post a screenshot of all your constraints for that view and the containing view?